# How to import Laravel Excel when the heading is at custom cells?

Tags: excel, database, laravel, laravel-excel

I want to import an excel file to my database using Laravel Excel. But my heading table is not at A1 cell but at custom cell like B2. This is the excel file:

[image]

And this is my import file :

```
namespace App\Imports;
use App\Mhs;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class MhsImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{

   public function collection(Collection $rows)
   {
      foreach ($rows as $row) {
         if ($row->filter()->isNotEmpty()) {
            // you logic can go here
            $mhs = Mhs::create([
                'nim' => $row['nim'],
                'nama' => $row['nama'],
                'jurusan' => $row['jurusan']
            ]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

**Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel**

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion